# The mean probability in a binomial event.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a series of N binomial (win/loss) events $e_i$ that can happens with different probabilities $p_i$. If i count the times $W$ that an event happens (the number of wins), the mean probability will be $\hat p = \frac{W}{N}$. What is the relation between $\hat p$ and $p_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In distribution, $\hat p$ can follow a variety of distributions on $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ since, for every $0\leqslant k\leqslant N$,
$$
\mathrm P(N\cdot\hat p=k)=\sum\limits_{|I|=k}\prod_{i\in I}p_i,
$$
where the sum runs over every subset $I$ of $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ of size $k$.
In the mean,
$$N\cdot\mathrm E(\hat p)=\mathrm E(W)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\mathrm P(\text{event}\ e_i\ \text{is a win})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^Np_i.
$$
Finally, by independence, the variance is such that
$$
N^2\cdot\text{Var}(\hat p)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^Np_i(1-p_i).
$$

Comment: i don't understand :( can you post here a proof or a reference?

Comment: What part? $ $ $ $

Comment: last two equations.

Comment: Do you agree that $W$ is a sum of $N$ random zeroes and ones, the $i$th term being 1 if and only if event $e_i$ happens?

Comment: yes. ...and so?

Comment: And so, by linearity of the expectation, E(W) is the sum of the expectations of these zero-or-one random variables. The expectation of the $i$th is $p_i$, this gives the formula for E(W).

Comment: ok, you right. one comment. you postulated that the $p_i$ are a sequence of 1 and 0's. That is true if you consider the $p_i$ as the actual frequency over one event. Now i can say that the $p_i$ are the theoretical probabilities. Now your statements are still valid?.

Comment: *you postulated that the $p_i$ are a sequence of 1 and 0's*... Absolutely not.